# Issue in connecting to Oracle DB from AWS DMS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I want to run a  DMS task to copy data from on premises Oracle DB to Mysql on AWS.
I have already got firewall access and am able to telnet to the oracle DB server from AWS ec2 instances. Also, I can login into the DB using the same username/pwd, connection string from sql developer
But when I test my endpoint on DMS , then it fails with below error.

FYI, the DMS instance falls in the same VPC for which I have got the firewall clearance.

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: ORA-12545: 
Connect failed because target host or object does not exist OCI connection failure.,
 Application-Detailed-Message: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 OCI connection failure. ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist OCI connection 
 failure. Command get_owner_list failed when creating the stream component. requested object was not found 
 in the repository. Failed getting stream handle requested object was not found in the repository. 
 create_stream_handle failed requested object was not found in the repository. 
 Getting DB object ('A4NOXXXXXXXXXK2N2U') info from repository failed requested object was not found in
 the repository. Command get_owner_list failed when creating the stream component. requested object was not
found in the repository. Failed getting stream handle requested object was not found in the repository. 
 create_stream_handle failed
```

I checked at both network and DB end an there seems to be no issue. Please suggest.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a network or firewall issue really; it sounds like either the connection configuration isn't correct, or the hostname in that configuration can't be resolved. When you test connectivity from the same VPC are you using an IP address or FQDN? And can you change the Oracle connection to use the same IP instead of an FQDN to eliminate a DNS issue?

Comment: what Oracle version are you trying to connect? did you have the TNSPING results to enrich the question?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem the other time, I assumed that the creation of DMS and Oracle instances using the same VPC would guarantee the connection between them. I also assumed that the addition of entry rules to open ports between the DMS and Oracle instances would also work, but the connection between them fails and I found two ways:

First: creating a DMS instance without a public IP address, the destination connection passes the validation. It worked the first time

Second: by opening the entry to allow all IP addresses, the connection between the instances will be successful.

Good Look!